DSL name for JOOQ generated entities
I am using jooq-codegen and I am upgrading jooq and H2 (jooq: 3.11.6 -> 3.19.3 , H2: 1.4.194 -> 2.2.224), DSL used to be lower_case and it is now UPPER_CASE.
For example
public AccountLinking() {
    this(DSL.name("ACCOUNT_LINKING"), null);
}

it used to be
public AccountLinking() {
    this(DSL.name("account_linking"), null);
}

I couldnt find anything meaningful in the release notes. H2 in both versions is creating tables with UPPER_CASE and the flyway SQL scripts have table names being lower_case.
Why is the code-gen different and how to fix this ?

Can you please show your complete code generation configuration

The question was crossposted here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/16570
